# Configure angularjs routes at runtime

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, routes

I've got my routing setup like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['MyApp.controllers']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/foo', {
        templateUrl: '/fooTemplate',
        controller: 'FooCtrl'
      });
    }]
  );
```

What I'd like to do is prefix a path to '/foo' at runtime, so depending on how my app is configured, the route might be /foo, might be /some/arbitrary/path/foo, etc.

Ideally I could write something like:

```
...
$routeProvider.when(prefix + '/foo', {
    templateUrl: '/fooTemplate',
...
```

But cannot figure out how to inject that prefix into my config method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
.when('/:prefix/foo', {templateUrl: 'details.html', controller: DetailsCtrl})
```

The `prefix` will then be available in the controller through [`$routeParams`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeParams). If you would like it to handle the option `foo` without a prefix just simply place it in the routing and make sure it is before the example above.

```
.when('/foo', {templateUrl: 'details.html', controller: DetailsCtrl})
.when('/:prefix/foo', {templateUrl: 'details.html', controller: DetailsCtrl})
```